# How to register mouse movements on a bottom component?

Tags: javascript, listener, parallax, mousemove

I am trying to register all mouse movements in red (bottom layer) and blue (upper layers) areas. Is there a way to add a Listener only to the red area? Because now I use this code:

```js
   red = document.querySelector('.red')
   blue = document.querySelector('.blue')
   red.addEventListener('mousemove', parallax);
   blue.addEventListener('mousemove', parallax);
```

(And not using common additional class, just adding a Listener to one component.)

[image]

Comment: Maybe pointer-events none? Need a bit more context.

Comment: Do you need to register it on all the layers?

Comment: @epascarello, I want to register one bottom layer (red), but events should happen even on blue areas. Is it possible?

Comment: Unless they are nested, probably not. You probably should bind the event listener to a parent and listen to the event there and do things with it.